# append ajax-jquery data into dropdownlist in cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Hi friends i am trying to append my ajax output into my dropdownlist....

My ajax function:-

```
 $.ajax({ 
     url: "getcolumn",
     data: {value: value},
     type: "POST",
     success: function(output) {
        var column = output;//here i am assigning the output to another variable
        var mySelect = $('#table_name');
        $.each(column, function(val, text) {
          mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
        });
```

My dropdown in form:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('Column', array(
    'label' => 'Select the column name below',
    'name' => 'tablename',
    'id' => 'table_name',
    'options' => array('null')
));
```

I want to append the output from ajax to the above dropdown box....
I have tried to append in my ajax success function, but not working. Can anyone help me out....
And the output is in the form of json.....

Comment: can you post the `json` output here?

Comment: ['id','venue','address',....]

Comment: i need to see the json structure and plz be specific what part of json you want to show in the option text.

Comment: I want to show id, venue , address in the options

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: "getcolumn",
 data: {value: value},
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json", //<----add this
 dataType: "json"                 //<----and this
 success: function(output) {
    var column = output;//here i am assigning the output to another variable
    var mySelect = $('#table_name');
    $.each(column, function(val, text) {
      mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text.id));
    });
 }
 });
```

Comment: Jai data is getting appended as NaN

Comment: and what about url passed in the ajax function? doesn't look good.

Comment: The url passed is correct, when i use alert box u i get correct values

Comment: try to put `absolute url` or `root relative url` then see what is coming in success function. `console.log(output) <---try this` and see what is coming in the console then.

Comment: oops your dataType is missing `dataType: "json"`

Answer (score 0):

i sugest to create correct json in your getcolumn script
for your jquery each to work the json should look like:

```
[{id: 86,label: "venue and address"}, {id: 87,label: "venue and address"}]
```

and then modify a bit your loop:

```
mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(text.id).text(text.label));
```